# Python: How to excute a variable in a string in a for loop in a function?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, survey

I have an excel (output of survey) and I am trying to write codes to give marks based on the entries of a survey of different students.

Suppose the data at hand is given as follow

```
import warnings, pickle
import numpy as np, pandas as pd

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

A='pickle.loads(b\'\\x80\\x03cpandas.core.frame\\nDataFrame\\nq\\x00)\\x81q\\x01}q\\x02(X\\x05\\x00\\x00\\x00_dataq\\x03cpandas.core.internals.managers\\nBlockManager\\nq\\x04)\\x81q\\x05(]q\\x06(cpandas.core.indexes.base\\n_new_Index\\nq\\x07cpandas.core.indexes.base\\nIndex\\nq\\x08}q\\t(X\\x04\\x00\\x00\\x00dataq\\ncnumpy.core.multiarray\\n_reconstruct\\nq\\x0bcnumpy\\nndarray\\nq\\x0cK\\x00\\x85q\\rC\\x01bq\\x0e\\x87q\\x0fRq\\x10(K\\x01K\\x04\\x85q\\x11cnumpy\\ndtype\\nq\\x12X\\x02\\x00\\x00\\x00O8q\\x13K\\x00K\\x01\\x87q\\x14Rq\\x15(K\\x03X\\x01\\x00\\x00\\x00|q\\x16NNNJ\\xff\\xff\\xff\\xffJ\\xff\\xff\\xff\\xffK?tq\\x17b\\x89]q\\x18(X\\x04\\x00\\x00\\x00Nameq\\x19X \\x00\\x00\\x00Which companies have you chosen?q\\x1aX\\n\\x00\\x00\\x00Question 1q\\x1bX\\n\\x00\\x00\\x00Question 2q\\x1cetq\\x1dbX\\x04\\x00\\x00\\x00nameq\\x1eNu\\x86q\\x1fRq h\\x07cpandas.core.indexes.range\\nRangeIndex\\nq!}q"(h\\x1eNX\\x05\\x00\\x00\\x00startq#K\\x00X\\x04\\x00\\x00\\x00stopq$K\\x04X\\x04\\x00\\x00\\x00stepq%K\\x01u\\x86q&Rq\\\'e]q(h\\x0bh\\x0cK\\x00\\x85q)h\\x0e\\x87q*Rq+(K\\x01K\\x04K\\x04\\x86q,h\\x15\\x89]q-(X\\x03\\x00\\x00\\x00Ayaq.X\\x04\\x00\\x00\\x00Ramiq/X\\x07\\x00\\x00\\x00Geniousq0X\\x05\\x00\\x00\\x00Samirq1G\\x7f\\xf8\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00X?\\x00\\x00\\x00                          Mobil,             ConsolidatedEdisonq2X?\\x00\\x00\\x00                    DataGeneral,         GeneralPublicUtilitiesq3h3X\\x11\\x00\\x00\\x00Uploaded the dataq4X\\xfe\\x00\\x00\\x00Uploaded the data,Specified the reason behind the selected stocks,You were successful in cleaning your data-sets,You have had a justification why you selected this particular time period of your chosen stock. This should have been answered in Question 2.q5X{\\x01\\x00\\x00Uploaded the data,Specified the reason behind the selected stocks,You selected both stocks from different industries,You were successful in cleaning your data-sets,You have had a justification why you selected this particular time period of your chosen stock. This should have been answered in Question 2.,You did extra work for this question and you deserve a round of applause.q6X\\xec\\x00\\x00\\x00Specified the reason behind the selected stocks,You were successful in cleaning your data-sets,You have had a justification why you selected this particular time period of your chosen stock. This should have been answered in Question 2.q7G\\x7f\\xf8\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00X(\\x01\\x00\\x00You plot a graph over the time axis that demonstrate how your selected returns behaved in exciting periods,You produced a scatter plot that shows that you may change your x-axis from time to market return.,You also were able to compare your selected stock to other stocks within the same industryq8X\\xde\\x01\\x00\\x00You plot a graph over the time axis that demonstrate how your selected returns behaved in exciting periods,You produced a scatter plot that shows that you may change your x-axis from time to market return.,You have shown some references to what has been going in your chosen period and you gave a good justification.,You also were able to compare your selected stock to other stocks within the same industry,You did extra work for this question and you deserve a very high mark.q9h8etq:ba]q;h\\x07h\\x08}q<(h\\nh\\x0bh\\x0cK\\x00\\x85q=h\\x0e\\x87q>Rq?(K\\x01K\\x04\\x85q@h\\x15\\x89]qA(h\\x19h\\x1ah\\x1bh\\x1cetqBbh\\x1eNu\\x86qCRqDa}qEX\\x06\\x00\\x00\\x000.14.1qF}qG(X\\x04\\x00\\x00\\x00axesqHh\\x06X\\x06\\x00\\x00\\x00blocksqI]qJ}qK(X\\x06\\x00\\x00\\x00valuesqLh+X\\x08\\x00\\x00\\x00mgr_locsqMcbuiltins\\nslice\\nqNK\\x00K\\x04K\\x01\\x87qORqPuaustqQbX\\x04\\x00\\x00\\x00_typqRX\\t\\x00\\x00\\x00dataframeqSX\\t\\x00\\x00\\x00_metadataqT]qUub.\')'

df1=eval(A)
```

I wrote these function to help me understand the meaning of applying or getting results

```
# This function will give you the students's answer {Answer_Student_1_Q_1, Answer_Student_1_Q_2}
def Get_student_answers_per_question(i1, total_number_of_questions):
    g=df1.index[df1['Name']!='Genious'][i1]
    Gen1=df1.ix[g,:]
    print(Gen1)
    for i in range(total_number_of_questions):
        if isinstance(Gen1[i+2], float):
            foo='Answer_Student_'+str(i1+1)+'_Q_'+str(i+1)+ '= Gen1['+ str(i+2) +']'
        else:
            foo='Answer_Student_'+str(i1+1)+'_Q_'+str(i+1)+ '= Gen1['+ str(i+2) +'].split(",")'
        exec(foo, locals(), globals())
    pass


# Get student score for each answer in question

def Get_score_per_question(student, question, dictionary_mark, total_number_of_questions):
#     Get_all_answers will get all the answers for student (student)
    Get_all_answers=Get_student_answers_per_question(student-1,total_number_of_questions)
    foo='Answer_Student_'+str(student)+'_Q_'+str(question)
    print(foo)
    v=[dictionary_mark.get(i) for i in exec(foo)]
    return v
```

Now in the last function, Get_score_per_question, I was trying to code

```
v=[dictionary_mark.get(i) for i in exec(foo)]
```

where v is the score of the variable if available in the answer of the dictionary.

so depending on the entries in the string variable foo the results would be of same length with numbers

The example that I am trying to run is this

```
student=1
question=1
dictionary_mark={'Uploaded the data': 1,
 'Specified the reason behind the selected stocks': 1,
 'You selected both stocks from different industries': 1,
 'You were successful in cleaning your data-sets': 2,
 'You have had a justification why you selected this particular time period of your chosen stock. This should have been answered in Question 2.': 1,
 'You did extra work for this question and you deserve a round of applause.': 1}
total_number_of_questions=2
Get_score_per_question(student, question, dictionary_mark, total_number_of_questions)
```

Where, as you can foresee, I will get the following error

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Can somebody help me in this regards, and is there any tutorial or page that someone could refer me to do a better coding in such surveys in python espcially when handling splits and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Docs of exec() function : https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec

> Be aware that the return and yield statements may not be used outside of function definitions even within the context of code passed to the `exec()` function. The return value is `None`.

And you have used this piece of code : `[dictionary_mark.get(i) for i in exec(foo)]`

So obviously the None object doesn't implement `__iter__` function and you get `Type Error` when you try to loop through

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to do my thing without the hassle of running string functions within functions?